# Using input titles as text for a div via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

html:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='settings'>Settings'</div>
<div id='menu'>
   Jobname <input type=text id='tipjob' title='this text should go into the tooltip' length='20'>
   Appname <input type=text id='tipapp' title='this text should as app text in the tooltip' length='20'>
</div>            
  <div id="build">Builds
      <div id="build-log">Build Log</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">Content
      <div id="tooltips">Tooltip</div>
  </div>
<div id='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tipjob').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#tooltips').fadeIn();
});
$('#tipjob').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#tooltips').fadeOut();
});
});
```

see css on jsfiddle too.

http://jsfiddle.net/yZZDd/433/

In above example (non working) i want to be able to fadein/fadeout some text when a person hovers over the input field. The text should go into the div "tooltips" which is hidden in css now (might not be the best way perhaps)

I dont need any other tooltip library's other then the default jquery (since i dont see the need for it, regarding tooltips)

So i am assuming i use the mouseenter/mouseleave per input field, then set a fadein fadeout but i dont know how to put the text from the input fields in there somehow.

Since i started with 1 input field i could just show and hide the div, but that became a problem with the second input field :)

Hope i explained it correctly. First timer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZZDd/447/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('#tooltips').text( $(this).prop("title") ).stop(1, 1).fadeIn();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('#tooltips').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks. This is working. Although i do notice that if you move from one input to another it acts "weird" you have to remove your mouse for the duration of the fadeout away from the input field in order for it to reset. But this could be a jquery thing perhaps?

Comment: I think you should use `stop(1,1)` in both `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/yZZDd/445/).

Comment: @SheikhHeera That's right - `stop(1,1)` helps indeed, but it's enough to use it only once - http://jsfiddle.net/yZZDd/447/

Comment: @Erik-JanRiemers, welcome and click the `tick sign` to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See this one: http://jsfiddle.net/yZZDd/448/

instead using `id` use `class`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tipjob').bind('mouseenter', function() {
      $('#tooltips').text('').text($(this).attr('title')).stop().fadeIn();
   });
   $('.tipjob').bind('mouseleave', function() {
      $('#tooltips').stop().fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Comment: This one works too, thanks. Although if you hover over it more times quickly it "remembers" it. As shown by zoltans answer, the stop can be used to not have this. (or see Sheikh Heera's sollution too)